# NameError (uninitialized constant ActiveStorage::Downloading)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am running Rails 6.0.3.2 and ruby 2.6.6

I am trying to use the ActiveStorage::Downloading class but can't figure out how to get it to load!
I am getting the error

```
irb(main):001:0>   include ActiveStorage::Downloading
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
NameError (uninitialized constant ActiveStorage::Downloading)
```

I'm pretty sure this is me, but I can't figure it out. I am using ActiveStorage already in the project, but want to use the `download_blob_to_tempfile` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, load the library by using `require` and `include` to use the methods of that module.

```
require 'active_storage/downloading'
include ActiveStorage::Downloading
```

Comment: Thanks. Having one of those kinds of days!